# I need PHP to download a file via SFTP using a PPK key and a password both on the key and on the account

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

First I installed phpseclib using the following instructions:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/pear.htm

But I'm getting this error message that says Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION in /usr/local/lib/php/Net/SFTP.php on line 512
I've tried connecting via telnet and I can connect to port 22 without problems, so I know it's not a firewall issue.
Mind you, I don't need to use phpseclib if there is an easier way to do this, such as a direct shell command since I already know the name of the file I'm downloading. I just don't know how to do that.

So here is my code so far:

```
<?php
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);
include'Net/SSH2.php';
include'Crypt/RSA.php';
include'Net/SFTP.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->setPassword('mypassword');

$rsa->loadKey('PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Public-Lines: 6
[base64 data]
Private-Lines: 14
[base64 data]
Private-MAC: [hex data]');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('myhostname', 22);

if (!$sftp->login('myusername', $rsa)) {
    exit('login failed');
    exit;
}

print_r($sftp->nlist()); // == $sftp->nlist('.')
print_r($sftp->rawlist()); // == $sftp->rawlist('.')
```

This prints out:
Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION in /usr/local/lib/php/Net/SFTP.php on line 512
login failed

---

Edit: I was asked to show log output. Here is some of it. It's really long and cluttered with cryptic hexadecimal that I removed most of to conserve space.

```
<-
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:4f:70:65:6e:53:53:48:5f  SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_
00000010  37:2e:32:70:32:20:55:62:75:6e:74:75:2d:34:75:62  7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ub
00000020  75:6e:74:75:32:2e:31:0d:0a                       untu2.1..

->
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69  SSH-2.0-phpsecli
00000010  62:5f:31:2e:30:20:28:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:6c:2c:20  b_1.0 (openssl, 
00000020  62:63:6d:61:74:68:29:0d:0a                       bcmath)..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.2463, network: 0.0733s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0001s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT (since last: 0.0247, network: 0s)
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY (since last: 0.1589, network: 0.1589s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.0311, network: 0.0001s)
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST (since last: 0.0011, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68  ....ssh-userauth
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT (since last: 0.1807, network: 0.1806s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68  ....ssh-userauth
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.0139, network: 0.0001s)
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK (60) (since last: 0.0735, network: 0.0734s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.0821, network: 0.0001s)
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS (since last: 0.0738, network: 0.0737s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:07:73:65:73:73:69:6f:6e:00:00:01:00:7f  ....session.....
00000010  ff:ff:ff:00:00:40:00                             .....@.
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0722, network: 0.0001s)
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_REQUEST_FAILURE (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (since last: 0.1085, network: 0.1084s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:80:00  ................
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0003, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09:73:75:62:73:79:73:74:65  ........subsyste
00000010  6d:01:00:00:00:04:73:66:74:70                    m.....sftp
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST (since last: 0.0732, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:20:00:00                          ..... ..
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00                                      ....
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09:00:00:00:05:01:00:00:00  ................
00000010  03                                               .
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF (since last: 0.0012, network: 0.0011s)
00000000  00:00:01:00                                      ....
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:0b:65:78:69:74:2d:73:74:61  ........exit-sta
00000010  74:75:73:00:00:00:00:01                          tus.....
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00                                      ....
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00                                      ....
```

---

Edit: this is what Filezilla does:

```
Status: Connecting to [host]...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
Command:    keyfile "C:\private_key.ppk"
Command:    open "[user@host]" 22
Command:    Pass: *********
Status: Connected to [host]
Error:  Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Does the library actually support putty key files?

Comment: You're asking me? Can you just tell me how to do this with a shell command?

Comment: Yeah, that's not how SO works. Maybe running `man sftp` in your shell will help you help yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Yes the library supports PuTTY key files, to answer your original question.

Comment: That you can connect on port 22 doesn't mean that SFTP is running. It doesn't even necessarily mean that SSH2 is running but I can tell from the error message that it is. What would be interesting is to see what you were actually getting in response. Could you post the log output? You can get it by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` and doing `$ssh->getLog()` right before the `exit('login failed')`

Comment: 1) Did you try to connect to the server using a standalone SFTP client? 2) What do you mean "connecting via telnet", do you mean SSH? SSH and Telnet are two different protocols. 3) What SSH client did you use 4) Do you really need both private key and password authentication?

Comment: From my home computer (Windows 7) I successfully connected to the remote server with an SSH client and yes it requires a password as well as a ppk key. From the PHP server though, I only connected to the remote server on port 22 with telnet just to make sure port 22 wasn't being blocked. Successfully. I didn't connect with an sftp client from the PHP server to the remote server, because I'm not familiar with how to do that from command line. Also thanks for your interest in this! I edited the original post and posted some log output above as requested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpseclib - Can I connect using username, key and password (Not a key password)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806699/phpseclib-can-i-connect-using-username-key-and-password-not-a-key-password)

Comment: One more thing. I was not able to log in from Filezilla on my home computer to the remote computer. That's why I used an SSH client instead (Bitvise)

Comment: What does FileZilla do? Show us its log + Show us a log from Bitvise too. I find it strange that phpseclib tries to start the SFPT server. I looks like it believes it authenticated.

Comment: Bitvise says "[...] Authentication completed. Terminal channel opened. STFP channel opened. STFP channel closed by server." See above for Filezilla's output.

Comment: I don't think your server supports SFTP. I'd post on superuser.com asking how to make your server support SFTP and post your Filezilla / phpseclib logs. According to the logs you're authenticating to the server without issue and the server is accepting the request from the client to open up an SFTP channel. It's just that the server is sending an EOF right after.

Comment: Thanks neubert. It definitely looks that way. I had been told that SFTP was confirmed to be working on the remote server, and that Filezilla was just buggy. So I was operating on those assumptions. But from the looks of things you are correct and SFTP isn't supported. I installed WinSCP and that didn't work either just to be sure. Thanks for all your attention to this.